# How to programatically bind a context specific JNDI resource

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

Is it possible to programatically bind a JNDI resource to a specific context? I think InitialContext.bind() binds the resource globally (it is visible to all the webapps). I want the resource to be visible only to a specific webapp. I am using tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in a lifecycle component in Tomcat, not from the webapp itself but declared in  `context.xml`. [Here](http://mo-tomcat-ext.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/extras/listeners/LogbackContextNameListener.html) is an example and  [here](http://mo-tomcat-ext.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html#LogbackContextNameListener) the declaration.

Comment: In your suggestion, `context.xml` is the wepapp's `context.xml`. Is there a way to accomplish the requirement without modifying any file of the webapp?

Comment: Not really, because you need to link a global resource if you don't declare it locally. You probably could with a global listener after the app has been started but I have never needed such an approach and I would not recommend such one either.

Comment: Yes I have a global listener, a LifecycleListener and I am not sure how to access the Context from LifecycleEvent opject that's passed to the listener.

Comment: My example exactly shows you how to access the context from the listener. You can declare your listener at host level. See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html#Introduction). That should suffice to solve the problem and accept the answer.